# Speed of object does not change (javascript, html canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created an enemy object so I can make multiple ones at once. I have the parameters for the object to take an x, y, speed of x, and speed of y. No matter what I put in the speed the red square (enemy) never moves.

```
    var c,
        ctx,
        cWidth,
        cHeight,
        xCenter,
        yCenter,
        iBack,
        Player,
        enemy1,
        scale = 40,
        speed = scale / 3;

    // Controll initialization
    var keyState = {};
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
        keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = true;
    },true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
        keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = false;
    },true);

    // Initial function to set canvas variables and start loop
    function init() {
      c = document.getElementById('canvas');
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');
      cWidth = c.width;
      cHeight = c.height;
      xCenter = cWidth / 2;
      yCenter = cHeight / 2;

      iBack = new Image(50, 50);
      iBack.src = 'pics/background1.jpg';

      Player =
      {
        playerX: xCenter - (scale / 2),
        playerY: yCenter - (scale / 2),
        speed: speed,
        draw: function() {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(Player.playerX, Player.playerY, scale, scale);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.closePath();
        },
        checkInput: function() {
          if (keyState[65]) {
            // A key
            Player.playerX = Player.playerX - Player.speed;
          } else if (keyState[68]) {
            // D key
            Player.playerX = Player.playerX + Player.speed;
          } else if(keyState[87]) {
            // W key
            Player.playerY = Player.playerY - Player.speed;
          } else if(keyState[83]) {
            // S key
            Player.playerY = Player.playerY + Player.speed;
          }
        }
      };

      // Enemy object
      function Enemy(x, y, speedX, speedY)
      {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.draw = function () {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(this.x + this.speedX, this.y + this.speedY, scale, scale);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.closePath();
        };
      }

      enemy1 = new Enemy(0, (cHeight / 2) - (scale / 2), 10, 10);

      setInterval(draw, 60);
    }

    function draw() {
      // Input
      Player.checkInput();

      // Draw Background
      //ctx.drawImage(iBack, 0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      // Draw Player
      Player.draw();

      // Draw Enemy
      enemy1.draw();

      // Collision
      playerCollision();
    }

    function playerCollision() {
      // Collision with walls
      if (Player.playerX <= 0) {
        Player.playerX = 0;
      } else if (Player.playerX + scale >= cWidth) {
        Player.playerX = cWidth - scale;
      } else if (Player.playerY <= 0) {
        Player.playerY = 0;
      } else if (Player.playerY + scale >= cHeight) {
        Player.playerY = cHeight - scale;
      }

      // Collsion with enemys

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything that causes the enemies `x` value to change. You're just drawing it with `x + speed`, but that won't make it move. That'll always just draw it one out.

Normally in your `setInterval()`, instead of calling `draw()` directly, make a function named something like `run()` which should do some work before calling `draw()` to show the changes from that work.

In `run()`, you should do something for each enemy like `enemy.x += enemy.speed`. Then, when you draw, each frame they'll move by speed.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!